# Convert a string to a list and back

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion, string-conversion

I feel like this is a strange request.
I'm starting with a string, and then I run that through a function that process the string (many lines) and returns a list.
This list contains timestamps, and text.  It's an LRC file, actually (Lyric with track time)

I'm writing a few kodi (xmbc) modules, and it runs its own python interpreter.  I can share data between addons but only as strings. (setting them as a property in kodi)

So, I have a list that I can convert to a string easily with str(), but I can't get it back into the same list that I can deal with.

Some example text:

```
[01:45.17]<i>I cant remember anything
[01:48.80]Cant tell if this is true or dream
[01:52.29]Deep down inside I feel to scream
[01:55.91]This terrible silence stops me
```

This comes back from my parser function as a list. In raw form looks like this:

```
[{'timestamp': dbus.Int64(105170L), 'id': dbus.UInt32(0L), 'text': 'I cant remember anything'}, {'timestamp': dbus.Int64(108800L), 'id': dbus.UInt32(1L), 'text': 'Cant tell if this is true or dream'}, {'timestamp': dbus.Int64(112290L), 'id': dbus.UInt32(2L), 'text': 'Deep down inside I feel to scream'}, {'timestamp': dbus.Int64(115910L), 'id': dbus.UInt32(3L), 'text': 'This terrible silence stops me'}]
```

Once I convert this to a string with str() it looks exactly like what is above as a string.

Now, I want to get this string back into the original list form. So that I can do line by line processes on it, and reference the elements, as I can with the pre-converted list:

```
print line['text']
print line['timestamp']
```

I've tried various things, but can't seem to get it back into a list I can loop through.

I looked at [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) ('lines' is the list):

```
lines_str=json.dumps(lines)
newlines=json.dumps(lines_str)

print newlines.__class__.__name__
```

But this tells me that lines is still a "str"
So, I tried with eval:

```
lines_str=str(lines)
newlines=eval(lines_str)
```

But eval doesn't like the string format:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./l.py", line 33, in <module>
    newlines=eval(lines_str)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
```

then I tried [literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) from the [ast](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) module:

```
lines_str=str(lines)
newlines=ast.literal_eval(lines_str)
```

But that liked my string even less.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

I could perform this task in one addon versus the other.  But in the spirit of design, I have a back-end that does the work, and the front-end that paints the pretty pictures.  I'd prefer to keep the work on the back-end and minimize loading modules and processes on the front-end piece.

Comment: Why are you `json.dumps`ing twice?

Comment: Because apparently through all my testing I forgot to change that to json.loads, which works. How about that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show exactly what is initially in `lines`.

Comment: It's the example text.  You can wrap lines="""  """ around if it makes you feel better!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in general, I would just use string formatting on each line separately, and then join them with newlines. I'll assume you have some function `from_dbus_int64` that turns a `dbus.Int64` into your timestamp format, since I don't know anything about dbus.

```
def from_parsed_line(line):
    return "{timestamp}{text}".format(
        timestamp=from_dbus_int64(line["timestamp"]),
        text=line["text"]
    )
```

Then you could just use `"\n".join(from_parsed_line(line) for line in lines)`.

One thing I noticed is that your sample had `<i>` in the first line but your parsed data didn't have it in the `text`. Unless you can explain to me why that is, I can't help you put that back in there. I assume you can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about format, but looks like you need pair of `json.dumps` (serializes data structure to string, which you have already) and `json.loads` (which do exactly opposite). And iterate and get keys/values you need after deserializing your strings.

Answer (score 0):

I did not write this function originally, and I don't know why the author used dbus.types.

So, there are two solutions:

Use json.dumps and json.loads correctly, which I was not doing.

Or, remove the dbus.types and used standard python types.
Doing the latter allowed me to convert using str() and eval() which is what I preferred over loading modules.

Thanks!